# WP Почему в preview mode не отображаються ACF переменные?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в состаянии Показать. `&preview=true`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображения которые были назначены через `ACF плагин` не показывает ? С чем это связано, и можно ли это исправить?

- Когда моя ссылка выглядит так - `https://test.local/what-is-bipolar-disorder/?preview_id=501&preview_nonce=9e52f3eb7a&preview=true` - поля с изображениями не доступны. `https://test.local/what-is-bipolar-disorder/?preview_id=501&preview_nonce=9e52f3eb7a` все показывает.